# How to setup a click toggle function for non-sibling when there are multiple elements with the same class?

Tags: jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/9jz3g6b2/

I do not want every $('.blue') to toggle when $('.red') is clicked, instead, I only want the immediately following $('.blue') to toggle.

```
<div class="clickme">
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>

<div class="comment">
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>

<div class="clickme">
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>

<div class="comment">
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>


<div class="clickme">
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>

<div class="comment">
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done in a single line in your `click` event:

```
$('.red').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().next().find('.blue').toggle();
});
```

Breaking it down:

1. On the `click` of `.red`...
2. Get the `parent()` of that `.red` ==> `.clickme`
3. Get the `next()` (sibling) of `.clickme` ==> `.comment`
4. Find `.blue` inside that `.comment`
5. `toggle()` its visibility

```js
$('.red').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().next().find('.blue').toggle();
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.green {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.blue {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="clickme">
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>

<div class="comment">
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>

<div class="clickme">
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>

<div class="comment">
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>


<div class="clickme">
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>

<div class="comment">
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```